# Why can't I print the value in register in NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to print the value in various registers in NASM, but first pass the value of the register to a memory variable before calling a macro that does the printf call.  It is not printing the actual value in the register, but I am unable to determine why.

```
extern printf

%macro OUTPUTREGISTERS 2

        section .data
        prmVal1 dq %1, 10, 0
        prmVal2 dq %2, 10, 0
        section .text
        mov rax, 2
        mov rdi, reg
        mov rsi, prmVal1
        mov rdx, prmVal2
        call printf

%endmacro



section .data
        reg db "%s %d" ,10, 0
        regValue dq 0
        regValue2 dq 0

section .text
        global main



main:
        push rbp
        mov rbp, rsp
        mov rax, 844
        mov rdi, 9393
        mov [regValue], rdi
        OUTPUTREGISTERS 'RDI', regValue
        mov rsp,rbp
        pop rbp
        mov rax, 60
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall
```

I am expecting it to print RDI 9393, but instead it prints: RDI 6293699

Comment: Have you looked at [Output Data Register value in NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920242/output-data-register-value-in-nasm)?

Comment: seems like you just started to learn assembly (judging by your lack of skill to debug this yourself), so I would like you to give you one advice... avoid macros first, there's nothing good in macros usage for new asm programmers, but usually many bad things happen, and they make debugging lot more difficult (the way you wrote that macro, it will not work as expected, and overall it's quite ugly to pollute final machine code with multiple injects of that crap). Also the second advice is to use debugger to check values in registers. Debug output is lot more tricky, even if you know asm.

Answer (score 1):

It is printing the address of prmVal2 rather than its value. But if you fix that, it still wouldn’t work, because prmVal2 contains the address of regValue, rather than its value.

I agree with @Ped7g’s advice to avoid using macros until you have the skills to identify this sort of problem, because they make such issues even more obscure.